# NSNotification in iphone

Tags: iphone, nsnotificationcenter

i am sending NSSNotifcation to another view controller in iPhone app but its observer method getting notified two times how its possible can any one guide me

i have use this code to post notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"updateStatusOnFacebook" object:nil userInfo:nil];
```

and added observer

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]   addObserver:self  selector:@selector(postToWall)                name:@"updateStatusOnFacebook"  object:nil];
```

Comment: I'd also put the string `@updateStatusFromFacebook"` into a variable / define so you're not having to type it out each time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you added the observer twice?

Which method are you calling addObserver:selector:object: in? If it's in viewWillAppear then this might be called more than once.

Your method will be called the same number of times that you have added an observer.

Try this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"updateStatusOnFacebook" object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(postToWall) name:@"updateStatusOnFacebook" object:nil];
```

---

The other reason is that you might just be sending the notification twice :)

Comment: no i am not sending notification two times and not observing it two times any other reason

Comment: Either you're adding it twice, observing it twice or your debugging is wrong :) How do you know you're not adding it twice?

Comment: as i have added it single time and added another observer for another notification i think its the problem of object identification i think i have to pass object from the class i am sending notification and have to observe using same object have any idea how to do it

Comment: No, if they're using different notification names then that won't be the problem. What happens if you add `NSLog` statements just before you add the observer and just before you post the notification - that should help you find out when the notification's are being sent / listened for

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem crop up, and read this question, but could only find the one call to add the observer anywhere in the project.

In our case, the observer *was* being added twice because the **method** the line was in was being *called* twice.

Make sure you step through your code, breaking on your `addObserver:selector:name:object` call, to ensure that you don't have an unexpected extra execution path to that call.