# NSNotification issue

Tags: iphone, ios, nsnotifications

i want to show the alert box in my whole applicaton when we got the response from my Signin

how it is possible?

can we use `NSNotification`?

Answer (score 0):

You could put a public method in your appdelegate and let it show your alertview.

You can access the app delegate like this:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate
```

You'll need to cast it to you app delegate class to prevent a warning, then you can send the message:

```
[(MyAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate showMyAlertView];
```

Comment: It's possibly better to leave the app delegate for pure lifecycle stuff and to put any global requirements like this into a different class. Once you start adding code to the app delegate, it tends to become a dumping ground for all sorts of global things that really should be encapsulated elsewhere.

Comment: Agreed partially, however it's main entry point and when it comes to displaying things it comes in handy to access some rootController through the app delegate without using a singleton or passing down that reference down the last niche in your code. However I think the OP just wants to show some alertView when an api returned positively, so my answer is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)afterSignIn
{
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple to create and receive notifications:

1) Add an observer (for example, it's `YourViewController`) to your notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(someEventHappend) 
                                                 name:@"SomeEvent" object:nil];
```

You should add this code in `viewDidLoad` method.

2) Implement `someEventHappend` method in `YourViewController`

3) Post notification when you've git response from Signin:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SomeEvent" object:nil];
```

After that `NSNotificationCenter` will call `someEventHappend` method on `YourViewController`

Answer (score 0):

@anil take one and set this in  Global.h  "BOOL Signin" value .When When it's true 
Then show 
Your alter view like this

```
-(void)afterSignIn
{
    if(Signin == YES)
    {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Meassage" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}
```

it is not compulsory to use NSNotificationCenter

Comment: or you check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816666/nsnotification-in-iphone